# Getting text from 2 edit texts and putting them in 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, android, android-studio, multidimensional-array

This is my main `java` class and i want to get text from 2 edit text view. Now i want to put that texts in the form of array like this. `textview1`,`textview2`,`textview1`,`textview2`......so on

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TableView tableView;
Button add,rej;
EditText breed, id;
String breed1;
static String[] header ={"Breed","ID"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tableView = (TableView) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    rej = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rej);
    breed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.breed);
    id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);

    tableView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2ecc71"));
    tableView.setHeaderAdapter(new SimpleTableHeaderAdapter(this,header));
    tableView.setColumnCount(2);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String result = breed.getText().toString();
            String result1 = id.getText().toString();
```

later after putting data in array i want to show the data in table. My table has 2 columns and it fixed but rows depends how much data i will enter.

```
            tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(MainActivity.this, myArray));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to put your data

```
class MyData {

    private String result = "";
    private String result1 = "";

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void setResult1(String result1) {
        this.result1 = result1;
    }
}
```

put your data in a list

```
  ArrayList dataArrayList = new ArrayList<MyData>();

  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String result = breed.getText().toString();
            String result1 = id.getText().toString();

            MyData myData = new MyData();

            myData.setResult(result);
            myData.setResult1(result1);

            dataArrayList.add(myData);
  }
```

then you can pass `dataArrayList` that is two dimensional array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou, i dont really understand it but i am getting error dataArrayList.add(myData);

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: @MutahirKiani Did you add this line? `ArrayList dataArrayList = new ArrayList<MyData>();`

Comment: @MutahirKiani Can you show you whole file? This answer works for me.